# Is there an Angular $scope event emitted after bindings have been applied to a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a directive in an Angular (1.4) application that uses the [`bindToController` option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-).  Here's my directive definition (written in TypeScript):

```
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public restrict = 'E';
    public templateUrl = 'path/to/my/template.html';
    public controller = 'MyController';
    public controllerAs = 'vm';
    public bindToController = true;
    public scope = {
        myScopeProperty: '@'
    };
}
```

This is working as expected - the `myScopeProperty` property is correctly bound to the controller.  However, this binding process happens after the object is constructed, which means I can't perform any logic that depends on the value of this bound property while the object is being constructed.  For example (again, in TypeScript):

```
export class MyController {

    public myScopeProperty;

    constructor() {

        // this logs "undefined", even if the my-scope-property 
        // attribute on the directive has a value
        console.log('myScopeProperty: ' + this.myScopeProperty); 
    }
}
```

Is there a `$scope` event I can listen to inside this controller object that is fired after Angular has finished applying its initial binding values to this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event and there's none should be, because one-way `@` binding means that `myScopeProperty` value may be updated multiple times.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.myScopeProperty', () => { ... }));
```

is the recommended way to watch for binding changes.

```
$timeout(() => { ... });
```

or [`$onInit` controller hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) (polyfillable in 1.4. with [angular-component](https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-component)) may be used to to postpone the code to a time when `myScopeProperty` has been already interpolated (the first time).

Comment: Thanks, `$onInit` was exactly what I was looking for.